# Is there a way of comparing 2 variables in a grid like way instead of nested if statements?

Tags: c#

I am dealing with a prisoners paradox type problem where there are multiple combinations (2x2 -> 4) and each has a different result. Is there a good way of looking at the inputs and deciding the output other than nested if statements which can get confusing if theres more than 2 options for inputs.
For example there are 2 prisoners being questioned: A and B. If both choose to expose the other then they both are imprisoned for 5 years, if both stay loyal then they both only recieve 1 year in prison, however if A exposes B but B remains loyal, A will be set free and B will be imprisoned for 10 years.
Currently my logic looks roughly like this:

```
if (A.Cooperate)
{
    if (B.Cooperate)
    {
        A.Sentence = 5;
        B.Sentence = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        A.Sentence = 0;
        B.Sentence = 10;
    }
}
else
{
    if (B.Cooperate)
    {
        A.Sentence = 10;
        B.Sentence = 0;

    }
    else
    {
        A.Sentence = 1;
        B.Sentence = 1;

    }
}
```

Although I would like to add more options than just a boolean yes/no and fear it will become over complicated with many nested if statements.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, but your question isn't clear enough to answer. What sort of computations are you doing on the "input" to get the "output", exactly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: The prisoner paradox is an example, input wether or not they cooperate, output the sentence each prisoner gets

Comment: So your expectation is that we'll go and learn about the prisoner paradox in order to help you with your question, instead of simply providing an example [mcve] of how you're doing things currently?

Comment: By the way, if your existing code is fully working, the question is better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (albeit not in a scenario where you're not providing code).

Comment: @Mars Please [edit] the question and provide a _concrete_ example (in the form of "I have abc and I want the result to be xyz"), focusing on a _specific **programming**_ problem, and preferably with whatever code you've already tried.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. The Prisoner's Paradox does not take a matrix as an input. The matrix is the *output*. The input is the decision of the two actors in the system.  Can you provide an exact specification of the inputs and outputs to your program? Is someone going to type something, or does it read a file? What does it print out? You must be able to specify these things in order to write any program.

Comment: At best `switch( (A.Cooperate?1:0) | (B.Cooperate?2:0) ) { case 0: .... case 3: }` or if you want names, then define an enum with flags.

Comment: Matrix approach in pseudo-code:  `S0 = 0; S1 = 1; S5 = 5; S10 = 10; var outcomes = [ [(S1,S1), (S0,S10)], [(S10,S0), (S5,S5)] ]; var outcome = outcomes[(int)A.Cooperates][(int)B.Cooperates]; A.Sentence = outcome.Item1; B.Sentence = outcome.Item2;` Will be more verbose in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it to improve readability and logic

```
    static void Interrogate(Prisoner A, Prisoner B)
    {
        if (!B.Cooperate && !A.Cooperate)
        {
            A.Sentence = 1;
            B.Sentence = 1;
        }
        else if (B.Cooperate && !A.Cooperate)
        {
            A.Sentence = 10;
            B.Sentence = 0;
        }
        else if (A.Cooperate && !B.Cooperate)
        {
            A.Sentence = 0;
            B.Sentence = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            A.Sentence = 5;
            B.Sentence = 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: surely much cleaner than OP code. Quite easy anyway to miss a combination of possible inputs, not suitable if the possible input combinations increase

Comment: @GianPaolo more combinations are not possible since the arguments are set at 2. For more there would be a abstract definition for the sentencing values, rather than hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new switch format

```
       switch (A.Cooperate, B.Cooperate) {
            case (true, false): {
                .....
                }
                break;

            case (true, true): {
                ....
                }
        }
```